# Translation API automatically translate text content to different Languages?

Tags: shopify

I am new to write a program. Recently, I am working on how to create a multiple language front store. After reading Shopify API document, I get confused about description and explanation, and sample code of the API documents. Perhaps I am not familiar to sample code written by GraphQL syntax. I hope someone who has such experience can response me directly.

> Can Shopify Translation API automatically translate text content to
> different languages if the translation content in other languages is
> not provided?
>
> Does the Shopify Translation API  play a role of google translation
> and translate text content automatically?

Answer (score 1):

For both the questions simple answer is: **No**

Shopify GraphQL API facilitates you to submit translated content for the objects like the product. it does not automatically translate anything.

You can make use of Google Translate API for translation.

How to implement it?

One can follow the below steps...

> STEP 1: Make GraphQL API call on the translatable resource to get the translatable resource of an object

```
$query = '{ translatableResource(resourceId: "'.$id.'") { resourceId translatableContent { key  locale digest } translations(locale: "hi") { key value } } }';
```

This will return a list of translatable content with digest ( a hash which is required to pass while writing translation [mutation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/graphql/graphql_mutation.htm) )

> STEP 2: Make GraphQL API call with mutation ( contains actual
>   translation data )

```
$query = 'mutation CreateTranslation($id: ID!, $translations: [TranslationInput!]!) { translationsRegister(resourceId: $id, translations: $translations) { userErrors { message field } translations { locale key value } } }';
```

> Variables You should pass

```
{
  "id": "gid://shopify/Product/154548888",
  "translations": [
    {
      "key": "title",
      "value": "تي شيرت ابيض",
      "locale": "ar",
      "translatableContentDigest" : 'a_long_hash_string', // provided in the first API call response
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hey. Can you please tell me whether it's possible to have multiple translationsRegisters (e.g. when you want to create a product) with an array of resourceIDs? TIA